# SQL - get device continous uptime

Tags: sql, gaps-and-islands

### Device uptime time series table

There is a device monitor table recording if a device is up (STATE 1) or down for each day.

```
DEVICE_ID, STATE, DATE
1          0      2017-10-09
1          1      2017-10-10
1          1      2017-10-11
1          1      2017-10-12
1          0      2017-10-13
1          1      2017-10-14
1          1      2017-10-15
1          0      2017-10-16
1          1      2017-10-17
1          0      2017-10-18
...
2          0      2017-10-10
...
```

### Question

How can I the duration of dates during which each device was up? The device 1 went up on 2017-10-10 and went down on 2017-10-13, hence it was up for 3 days (10, 11, 12). Then 2 days from 2017-10-14 to 2017-10-15.

The expected result should look like below.

```
DEVICE_ID, STATE, DATE
1          3      2017-10-10
1          2      2017-10-14
1          1      2017-10-17
```

Please advise.

Comment: What `DBMS` are you using (i.e. Postgres, MySql)?

Answer (score 2):

This is a gaps-and-islands problem.  You can solve this version with the difference of row numbers:

```
select device_id, min(date), max(date), count(*) as num_days
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by device_id order by date) as seqnum,
             row_number() over (partition by device_id, state order by date) as seqnum_2
      from t
     ) t
where state = 1
group by device_id, (seqnum - seqnum_2), state;
```

Why this works is a little tricky to explain.  If you stare at the results of the subquery, you will see how the difference between the two row number values defines the adjacent values that you want.